# PHP If Function inside Variable

Tags: php

How can I add `if` function in my PHP code below :

```
$html = 'blabla
'.if($a = $b).'
{
}
';
```

When I run that code, it show error like this :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in...
```

Please help to advice.

Thanks.

Comment: That is not possible when defining a variable.

Comment: Is there any way to solve that?

Comment: What do you want to do with this?  There is likely a much better way

Comment: **Why on Earth would you do that?** The only reason is to execute user input and that opens you up, if you are a beginner, as it seems you are, to a world of pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a ternary operator.

Example:

```
$html = 'blabla' . ($a == $b ? 'write something' : 'or something else');
```

Comment: You don't even know what he's trying to do.  How can you give an answer?

Comment: He's trying to add an if statement in the middle of a string. This is the best way to do it (according to me).

Comment: You will need to put parentheses around the ternary statement, otherwise you will not get the expected result. In the above code (without parentheses), `'blabla' . ($a == $b)` is seen as the expression (not `($a == $b)`), since `.` (string concatenation) has a higher precedence than `?:` (ternary).

Answer (score 1):

use append again to string and use `==` to compare like

```
$html = 'blabla';
if($a == $b){
$html .='yes';
}
```

or use ternary operator like @Viktor Svensson answer

Comment: Hi.. I need that IF function inside the html variable

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this.

```
<?php

$html = 'Your order was ';

if ($order->status === 'success') { // I don't know just doing something random
    $html .= ' successful';
} else {
    $html .= ' unsuccessful';
}
```